# how to make crossfilter.js recognize items being added or removed

Tags: meteor, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on a meteor.js app, which makes use of d3.js and crossfilter.js to create an interactive multi-chart cross-filtered dashboard.
An important part of the desired functionality is to have the individual charts adjust in real time, when a record is either added to the underying MongoDB collection, or is removed from it.
The reactivity part is not an issue -

```
Template.chart.rendered = function () {

        Tracker.autorun(function(){
                yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
            console.log('autorun is called');
        });
}
```

The issue is to make the crossfilter aware of the changes, which , I hope, will force the individual charts to re-adjust in response to crossfilter changes.

By simply adding the following line to the autorun:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
                yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
                ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);
            console.log('autorun is called');
        });
```

did not make any difference.
What else do I need to do to have those charts adjust?

Comment: I've restructured my autorun code as such  Tracker.autorun(function(){
            yelp_data = {};
            ndx = crossfilter();
            yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
            ndx.add(yelp_data);

                if(Session['loaded'] === true){
                    dc.redrawAll();
                }
            console.log('autorun is called');
        });       but this made no change - the chart (dc.js) does not redraw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [crossfilter.add](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_add) and [crossfilter.remove](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_remove) to add and remove data from a Crossfilter that has already been created. Crossfilter.remove is annoying because it requires you to change your filters in place to remove specific records. It's on a very long todo-list to fix [this pull request](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/pull/11) to allow removal of arbitrary records.

Once the Crossfilter is updated, you will need to trigger update of any charts that are based on the Crossfilter. If you are using dc.js, this is just a matter of calling dc.redrawAll for whatever chart groups you've defined.